# defer an async call in node until all awaits from caller finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

TL;DR: is it possible to say *"call that function once all awaits in the current context finish"* in JS/node?

A very simplified example:

- a frontend-facing service creates a new user, then does another async task (`[1]`) and returns
- a user service validates & saves the new user, then fires an event (`[2]`) that can trigger some other logic (unrelated to the current request)
- **goal: `[1]` should always finish before handlers for `[2]` start running**

```js
class Service1 {
  // say this is called from a controller / express route handler
  async createUser(userData: NewUserData): Promise<UserWithAdditionalData> {
    const user = await this.userSerivce.validateAndSaveUser(userData);
    // [1] this is also async, and should finish before [2] handlers start running
    const userWithData = await this.getSomeAdditionalData(user);
    return userWithData;
  }
}

class UserService {
  async validateAndSaveUser(userData: NewUserData): Promise<User> {
    const validatedData = await this.validateNewUserData(userData);
    await this.dbService.saveNew(validatedData)
    // [2] trigger an event/hook to be executed later
    this.eventBus.onUserCreated();
  }
}
```

**The question**: is it possible to implement/replace `[2]` in a way to achieve the mentioned goal? Preferably in a better way than scheduling the event a few seconds in the future :D

In my current implementation, I'm using an [event bus library](https://github.com/Dashlane/ts-event-bus/), that calls registered event consumers when an event is triggered. However, since it's probably just pushing the callback onto the event loop under the hood, it's likely to be executed before `[1]` because both will just be queued onto the event loop. For the same reason, the same happens if I wrap the handlers in `setTimeout(..., 0)` or `setImmediate`. What I want to achieve, is that the event handlers should be fired *after* all the `await`s from the caller are finished.

*// please let's avoid discussing if the pattern above is a good design -- like most things, it can be used both in good and bad ways ;)*

Comment: Why do you care? I'd say it depends on your objective for how to best solve this

Comment: The most trivial solution would be to move the `this.eventBus.onUserCreated();` call into the service1, after the `await`s that it is supposed to wait for. Or to answer your title question: no, there is no way to access the caller context - if you need something like that you'll need to pass the context explicitly.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, but in more complex examples there are many reasons why I wouldn't want to move it there. For example, there can be many different ways to call user creation, and it's the user service that's responsible for handling that and firing the event.

Comment: But when there are many different calls, there are also many different things it would need to wait for before firing the event?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I'm asking if there is a method to schedule firing an event when all the caller's `await`s are finished :) Scheduling them until the current request processing is finished also would be good enough in some cases.

Comment: No, there's not, and it would be too fragile anyway. If you'd refactor the caller, e.g. inlining it elsewhere, the behaviour of your code would change drastically. Worst case, you're calling `validateAndSaveUser` from the main function, it would never fire the event before the application ends.

Comment: "*Scheduling them until the current request processing is finished*" - that's a quite different thing. For that, just pass the "current request" into the function, and hook your event firing onto its finish event. (This could be a promise that fulfills when the response stream is closed, for example)